# If $B$ is an $n \times m$ matrix such that $B\vec{x}_i=\vec{0}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,k$, prove that $B\vec{y}=\vec{0}$ for every $\vec{y}\in V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V=\operatorname{span}\{\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2,\ldots,\vec{x}_k\}$ where $\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2,\ldots,\vec{x}_k\in \mathbb R^n$.
If $B$ is an $m \times n$ matrix such that $B\vec{x_i}=\vec{0}$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots,k$, prove that $B\vec{y}=\vec{0}$ for every $\vec{y}\in V$.

I am not quite sure how to approach this proof, but for sure I know that I should involve linear combinations. A starting point and guidelines are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$V=\text{ span }\{\vec{x_1},\vec{x_2}...,\vec{x_k}\}$ is equivalent to saying that for any $\vec{y}\in V$, there are constants $c_1,c_2,...c_k$ such that:
$$\vec{y}=c_1\vec{x}_1+c_2\vec{x}_2+...+c_k\vec{x}_k$$
thus, for any $\vec{y}\in V$:
$$B\vec{y}=B\big(c_1\vec{x}_1+c_2\vec{x}_2+...+c_k\vec{x}_k\big)=c_1B\vec{x_1}+c_2B\vec{x_2}+...+c_kB\vec{x_k}=0$$